# PhpMyAdmin wrong display in Nginx using reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, reverse-proxy

- I am running a NodeJS application in Nginx with a reverse proxy to port 3000
- PhpMyAdmin is configured and *apparently* runs in /phpmyadmin
- **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** is configured like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; 
    }
}
```

I managed to make all work as I wanted, but PhpMyAdmin has a bad display:

[image]

Before setting the reverse proxy in that file, PhpMyAdmin ran perfect. I assume there is something I missed in `default` file. 
 Any ideas? Thanks

---

**To Ivan Shatsky's Response:** @IvanShatsky

I tried substituting with your code, but it downloads a file (it does not read .php files) - So, I added few more lines:

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /phpmyadmin/index.php$is_args$args;
    
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

The result is the same before.
When I check the resources of the network, this is what happens:
[image]

I have performed `chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/phpmyadmin` but no changes. Would I need to have https? - I am currently trying on http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder how it is running at all. Assuming your phpMyAdmin located in the `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin` directory, try this:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /phpmyadmin/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ivan I have added an update in the question according to your response, thanks.

Comment: @J.Diaz My mistake, `^~` wasn't needed, try updated `location` block as is, there is no needs to add fastcgi configuration inside it. But since you're receiving 403 Forbidden I'm afraid that the cause of your problems is incorrect permissions on phpMyAdmin assets files. Another possible cause is incorrect SELinux labeling, do you have SELinux enabled on your server?